# Xcode doesn't recognize iOS version change

Tags: xcode

I have an app in Xcode that uses iOS version 10.0.

Recently I try to create a dark theme and create a new color(with any and dark appearance) on Assets.xassets

But when I try to compile my app, I received the following error:

"Named colors do not work prior to iOS 11.0"

So, I change iOS version to 11.0 and try to compile it again.

The same error appears.

I change it to iOS 12.1, the error still persists.

I think Xcode didn't recognise the iOS version change, how can I fix that?

Comment: When you say "I change the iOS version", what exactly are you doing? Assuming that you're changing it in the right place, have you tried cleaning the build target?

Comment: Yes, I clean the project. I click on "Product" -> "Clean Build Folder". Didn't change nothing.

Comment: When I say "I change the iOS version", what I do is click on project name, then click TARGETS -> Deployment Info and click on iOS 10.0. Check this image - https://snipboard.io/5sQarm.jpg

Comment: What destination are you compiling for? A simulator? What's the iOS version on that simulator?

Comment: @matt I was compiling against the iOS simulator. The iOS version on the simulator is 14.4. Xcode does not allow me to compile the code.

Comment: From your screen shot it looks like you changed the _target_ deployment version but not the _project_ deployment version. Is that possible?

Comment: I didn't know that there was a difference between target deployment version and project deployment version. Yes, that's possible. But I change it now the project deployment version to 13 and I still got the error: Illegal Configuration - "Named colors do not work prior to iOS 11.0"

Comment: Weird. Maybe you are using a framework that uses a lower version.

Comment: I use a cocoapod library, that uses (platform :ios, '9.0'), but I guess this is a minimum ios version, not a maximum ios version

Comment: Can you be more specific as to where that error is being generated? Simply including a color asset would not produce that error. The point of usage would and that could lead to some clues....

Comment: @Eric Shieh I include a color asset in Assests.xcassets and after that I set that color asset to a background View. This is enough to produce that error. Take a look on that video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASV7i7TT7X0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there is another deployment target for your storyboard file that you need to change:
[image]